# Navigation Drawer is slow with complex view

Tags: android, performance, view, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

In my app i'm using Navigation Drawer and it works very fine. But if the Fragment to show contains much TextView, ImageView and Layout, when i click the item, the view is glitching. I would improve this lag. The effect is the same by my Galaxy Nexus and with Nexus 4 so i think the problem is that i have 2 comands in the same time.

```
  //On item click - First comand (Close Drawer) 
  mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
  setTitle(mStringTitles[position]);
  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerView);

    // Second comand (Replace Fragment)        
    getFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.firts_view, new FragmentNew())
   .commit();
```

So I thought I'd replace the fragment just after the menu is closed .. any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html):

```
Avoid performing expensive operations such as layout during animation as it can cause stuttering;
try to perform expensive operations during the STATE_IDLE state.
```

What you could do, is have an event listener for your drawer, and do the fragment operation in the onDrawerClosed callback ([example here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you load the views in the fragment in the `onCreateView()` method it will slow down the fragment loading. Try loading the fragment related views in the `onStart()` method.